# How to image zoom on ManipulationOrigin with LayoutTransformation and scrollviewer (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, image-manipulation, scrollviewer

I'm working in a WPF project where I have to zoom an image, hence scrollviewer is needed when the image is zoomed.

I have achieved the zoom with delta manipulation matrix etc.

The problem is, using RenderTransform, scrollviewer doesn't work because i'm guesssing it assumes the position/layout never change.
But when I use LayoutTranform, the scrollviewer works fine, but I can't zoom to the mouse position (ManipulationOrigin).

Is there a way I can achieve image zoom to `ManipulationOrigin` with `LayoutTransformation` and `scrollviewer` (WPF C#)

With this code:

```
ImageCanvas.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
```

`scrollviewer` doesn't work, but image manipulation to mouse position / `ManipulationOrigin` work fine.

But with this code:

```
ImageCanvas.LayoutTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
```

`scrollviewer` works fine but image manipulation to mouse position / `ManipulationOrigin` doesn't work.

Basically, I need both `scrollviewer` and image manipulation to mouse position to work.